# How to autofill formula when new column is added

Tags: excel

I don't understand how can I autofill a formula that is on a cell to a new column added on the left.
Let's make an example:
[[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufCvH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcV5c.png)
I have on cell "B2" a date that is "B1+180", when I add a new column on the left of "B2", the new "B2" does not contain the formula. How can it autofill the formula when adding new column on the left?

Thanks.

I'm expecting that when I add a new column on the left of "B2", the new B2 will autofill the formula "B1+180".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented in aclayden's answer you can do this with VBA

Using a worksheet change event we can watch a cell for any changes and if there is a change, add the formula.

Right click on the Sheet tab, then click View Code.

In the VBAproject box you should see the sheet you want to be watching, if it is not the correct sheet, double click on the sheet's name that you want.

You should now have the area where you can paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' set the target worksheet name here

If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Range("B1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then  ' set the cell to be watched
        
    ws.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+180" ' set the cell where you want the formula - The formula will need changing if you want to refrence another cell.

End If

End Sub
```

Make sure you change sheet names and cell references in the code to match your reequipments, if you change cell references then you will need to change the formula.

You can now go back to the sheet and add a new column, this should now add the formula automatically.

Comment: Yes it works, but it set this to all the row of the new column. How can I set this just for row D4, D8, D12, D16 for example?

Comment: It works for the issue described in your original question, but there was no mention of the D cells. If it is only going to be those cells thet you have just mentioned then you could add more lines of code targeting those particular cells.

Answer (score 0):

Could you copy and insert the existing column? That would copy/paste the formulas with it as long as your references were static, e.g. $A$1, not A1. If you need the formula to be pulled down over rows you can use $A1, but if the column reference is dynamic you'll end up looking to the wrong cell or creating a #REF error.

This can be achieved more easily with inserted rows by formatting the range as a table, but insert should as described above.

Comment: I need that it should be automatically, whitout copy/paste. I want the user that just add new column on the left of that cell and fill just "B1" with the new date and then automatically "B2" will make (=B1+180). Do you think that this is not possible?

Comment: This would need VBA to achieve. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Yes ofc, can you explain it with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel Autofill works automatically when creating a new column. What you could do is better write your formula with absolute or semi-absolute reference to B1 ($B1, B$1 or $B$1), create new columns and then use the "black plus" to extend your formula by Autofill. Another way could be to copy-paste the entire B column onto the left of it self: if your formula is well-written, it'd word also.